# Upgrade EDMX to EF 4.0 - update model to include foreign key columns

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, foreign-keys, edmx

Upgrading my ASP.NET 3.5 / Entity Framework 1.0 solution to .NET 4.0, I would like to take advantage of the *foreign key* columns that can be part of your EDMX model as of EF 4.0.

I tried just basically updating my EDMX model from the database and ticking that "Include foreign key columns in model" option in the "Update Model from Database" wizard - unfortunately, that didn't seem to do anything at all...

Sure - I could just remove all the tables from my model and re-import them - but that way I'd lose all my modifications I've made to the model classes.

Is there some trick or tweak or external tool or something to make "Update Model from Database" to detect and include the foreign key columns in my EDMX model after I've upgraded to EF 4.0 - without having to drop and re-import all tables?

Comment: as per the email you sent...hmmm I *dont* know how to do this without doing it manually - i.e. adding new props to each entity and mapping, the deleting and recreating/defining each association. I wonder if there's a trick. The SSDL is already aware of the FKs wo UPDATE won't pick them up just because you check the use FKs option.

Comment: Did you give a try to [Huagati DBML/EDMX Tools](http://www.huagati.com/dbmltools/)?